# How to scrape a website which requires login using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

i want to webscrpe this website and i need to login to get the account datail (https://online.cspension.com.hk/hkpensionweb/#/login?source=corporateHK&vgnLocale=en_CA), i don't want to use selenium

how to login and get the account datail

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `requests.Session()` instance to make a post request to the login url with your login details as a payload. Making requests from a session instance is essentially the same as using requests normally, it simply adds persistence, allowing you to store and use cookies etc.

```py
import requests

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
    'inUserName': 'username',
    'inUserPass': 'password'
}

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('LOGIN_URL', data=payload)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print p.text

    # An authorised request.
    r = s.get('A protected web page url')
    print r.text
        # etc...
```